# What is the name of the sister and what is the town in this passenger list?

Tags: 20th-century, palaeography, russia, poland

I am trying to research my husband's grandparents. They arrived in St. Albans, Vermont, in 1913 from or through Canada, emigrating from Poland/Russia. This is from the column that states who is their nearest relative in the country they are alien from. The top image is showing more of the handwriting to help with deciphering, and the second one is a crop in of what I am interested in which is lines 5-8 of the first image.

[image: For Handwriting deciphering]

What I have made out is that it is his sister, "Agatha Kolenda?," and they are from  "Korole Volusby" (or Volusky), "Russia." Could someone tell me, from the image below, if I am right about the sister's name and where she lived, and where this place may be in Russia?

[image: Russia area]

Comment: Hi, Cathy, welcome to G&FH.SE. While you are waiting for an answer about the handwriting in this record, you may find this article of interest: [By Way of Canada: U.S. Records of Immigration Across the U.S.-Canadian Border, 1895-1954 (St. Albans Lists) By Marian L. Smith](http://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2000/fall/us-canada-immigration-records-1.html) -- it gives more information about The 'St. Albans lists'.

Comment: Is this from the column that records the name and address of the relative or friend in the passenger's county?

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to reflect what you asked in the body of the question, and I've added tags to show that you have a handwriting question and that your question may also relate to Poland (which was mentioned in your original title).  This is to help others find your question.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include what you think the three words may be?  I think the last one is "Russia" and that the first one starts with a "K" and the second one ends in a "y" but not much else.

Comment: I read:  Ko?v?olo, volinsk?y , russia

Comment: It helps when you are asking about handwriting interpretation to include more of the page written by the same hand. This helps with understanding how the author writes. You may get a more accurate answer this way.

Comment: Thank you Jan Murphy for your additions. Also, thank you PolyGeo and Sam. Colin, I did add an image of more of the page to help with deciphering the handwriting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it might be Kovel.

This link will also help. It says:

"Volinsky = Volhynia. Prior to WW I, this was a province wholly within Russia. Between 1921 and WW II, it was split in half with the west being in Poland and the east remaining in Russia. Today it is wholly in Ukraine."

http://boards.ancestry.com/thread.aspx?mv=flat&m=21349&p=localities.ceeurope.poland.unknown

Map of the province here: http://www.rollintl.com/roll/volhynia.htm.

Comment: Thank you user3310902, I think you are right. I checked out the links and they were really helpful. Now to compare the maps to one of the area now.